# Sending email when a date count down is triggered

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to set up a sheet with varying email address and 
dates. when a date (due) counts down to 20 say, I'd like to send the 
owner of the issue an automatic email. All info in in the same row 
just varying columns. I post my semi-functional script here, I can get the correct line item to pull based on date, I just cant get the script to pull the associated email with the date. Or I get a ton of emails that i dont want. [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k70Iy8K142LvFZqeeFzEb62EBIcVUmeazKhSuVbgJ3E/edit#gid=0)
Any help would be much appreciated!!

```
function checkReminder() {
// get the spreadsheet object
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// set the first sheet as active
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);

// fetch this sheet
var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

// Number of rows to process
 var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   

// figure out what the last row is
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

// the rows are indexed starting at 1, and the first row
// is the headers, so start with row 2
var startRow = 2;

// Fetch the range of cells A2:B3 
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2 ,lastRow, 
sheet.getLastColumn());

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Logger.log(data)

 // grab column 20 (the 'days left' column) changed  numrow to last r 
row 
get last row change
var range = sheet.getRange(startRow,20,lastRow-startRow+1,1 );
var numRows = range.getNumRows();
var days_left_values = range.getValues();

// Now, grab the reminder name column
range = sheet.getRange(2, 16, lastRow-startRow+1, 1);
var reminder_name_values = range.getValues();

var warning_count = 0;
var msg = "";
//msg = msg + "Trial Reminder Trial: "+reminder_name+" is due in 
"+days_left+" days.\n"

//for (i in data) {
// var row = data[i];

// First column
//  var emailAddress = row[13];  

// Recipe column (Priority HIGH)
 // var message = row[14]; 
 // var subject = "Reminder CAPA ";
//subject = subject + reminder_name;

// Loop over the days left values
for (var k = 0; k <= numRows-1; k++) {
var days_left = days_left_values[k][0];
if(days_left == 20) {

  // if it's exactly 20, do something with the data.
  var reminder_name = reminder_name_values[k][0];

  msg = msg + "Reminder CAPA: "+reminder_name+" is due in 
"+days_left+" days.\n";
  warning_count++;
}
if(warning_count) {
//MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message); 
Logger.log(msg);

}  

}}
```

Comment: In order to understand correctly about your situation, can you provide a sample spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information. It will help users think of about your issue.

Comment: I have attached the sheet i am working with.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although in my environment, I couldn't see the shared spreadsheet, other users might be able to see it.

Comment: I have updated the sheets share profile to 'anyone with the link'. I appreciate any help in this project!